# Jump to error using rosmake and Emacs

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I'm just getting started working with ROS. My usual workflow is to edit code in Emacs, and compile from Emacs. Then I can jump to errors in the code by pressing C-x`. However, when using rosmake, this doesn't work.

What is the best way to integrate rosmake with Emacs? I tried installing rosemacs, but that mode seems to have no support for compiling, but rather browsing ros nodes, etc.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64745/jump-to-error-using-rosmake-and-emacs/) by [The Martin](https://answers.ros.org/users/5112/the-martin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2013-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I generally run **M-x compile** and replace the "make -k" in the minibuffer with:

```
 cd ../..; rosmake
```

From then on it will remember your last compile command, and **C-x `** works as usual.

You need to use the right number of ".." references to reach the top of your package. Rosmake does not work from a subordinate directory.

I'd love to hear a more elegant solution, but that works OK for me.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1